# Double quotient integral formula on $\Gamma \backslash G /K$

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, haar-measure

Let $G=\text{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$, $\Gamma=\text{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ and $K=\text{SO}(n,\mathbb R)$. Consider the double coset space $X= \Gamma \backslash G /K$ and its fundamental domain $\mathcal F\subset G$ (the measure on $X$ is not Haar but when $n=2$ I know there is a hyperbolic measure $\frac{dxdy}{y^2}$). The classical quotient integration formula gives, for example, that for any compactly supported function $f\in C_C(G)$, we have

$$\int_{G/K}\left(\int_K f(gk)d\mu_K(k)\right)d\mu_{G/K}(gK)=\int_Gf(g)d\mu_G(g)$$

Similar formula holds true for $\Gamma \backslash G$.

I wonder if this is can be generalized to some quotient integration formula on $X= \Gamma \backslash G /K$. One speculation is

$$  \int_{\Gamma} \int_{\mathcal F}  \int_{K}f(\gamma g k)d\gamma dg dk = \int_G f(g) dg \tag{*}$$

Even for the case $n=2$, I don't know how to prove such a formula (or any form similar to (*)). I am also fear a little about this because such things cannot be find in the literature I am aware of. Any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: The easier thing is to prove it the same way prove the $n=2$ case, you get a positive functional from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is $G$-invariant, so one just need to worry about normalization [ps even in $n=2$, the measure on $X$ is the measure induced from the Haar measure].

[cont.]

Comment: For the general case, if $f$ is a spherical function, the equivalence of the formulas follows from the quotient formula for $\Gamma \backslash G$, see for example Bourbaki/Weil. If $f$ is not spherical, decompose it to its $K$-types, the $K$-integral of any non-trivial $K$-type is zero (hence also the $G$ integral, using say the Cartan decomposition and the explicit formulas for the Haar measure there) and you are left with the spherical part. This works for every function $f$ in say $L^{2}(G)$ with compact support or so.

Comment: @Asaf how do we prove $f \mapsto \int_{\Gamma} \int_{\mathcal F}  \int_{K}f(\gamma g k)d\gamma dg dk$ is $G$-invariant and why $n \ne 2$ is different?

Comment: The $n=2$ case is the same as the general case. It would be easy to start by dealing with spherical functions first, hence you can drop the $dk$ integral, then you just need to worry about $\int_{\Gamma}\int_{F}f(\gamma x)d\gamma dg(x)$.
Replacing $x$ by $xg$, amounts to putting in $\Delta(g^{-1})dg$ in the inner integral by the substitution rule, but $\Delta \equiv 1$ as the group is unimodular (a nicer argument would say that it amounts to looking at $F\cdot g$ which is another fundamental domain etc etc).
Using $K$-types, each (non-spherical) isotypical component maps to zero for both int

Comment: Let $H=\Gamma\times K$, and define a left $H$-action on $G$ by $(\gamma,k)\cdot g=\gamma gk^{-1}$. Now apply the well-known homogeneous space integration formula for $H\backslash G$ (see Bourbaki, Integration II, Ch.7--9).